# Receive a file with commands as parameter in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question maybe i'll find some answers from you .

Well , i want to write an interpreter that receives a file with commands as parameter in nodejs

For example :

```
node test.js robot.s
```

robot.s contains :

```
# Move
FORWARD 100
COMMAND_WITH_ERROR 
BACKWARD 6
```

Any ideas how i can start ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To read the parameters you should look into https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

```
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
    console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
});
```

As listed in the link this should print you with index 0 the path to your nodejs binary, Index 1 is the path to the file you try to execute with node, 2 and higher give you the "actual" parameter.

So you could just do something like this to read the file

```
fs = require('fs');
parameter = process.argv[2];
fs.readFile("./" + parameter, function(err, data) {
  //do things with the data from the file
```

Because I don't exactly know what commands your interpreter should have and how you want to structure it, that is all I can help for now. But that should at least get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply . my interpreter receives a file , as i mentioned abbove which contains : `# Move
FORWARD 200
COMMAND_WITH_ERROR 
BACKWARD 10` , and my interpreter should output : `OK 200, 0, 90
ERROR LINE 2: Unknown command COMMAND_WITH_ERROR
OK 190, 0, 90`